# Custom Numeric Suffix Passable through Arguments in C#

Tags: c#, coordinates, suffix

I have a application that passes around "custom" 3D coordinates. The coordinates can either be absolute or relative.

I've been thinking about quick ways to express this for each value, x, y, z, without having to have a multidimensional array containing the value and a boolean about whether the value is relative or absolute.

Example of what I'm trying to avoid:

```
Coordinate c = new Coordinate({100.0,true},{25.0,false},{100.0,true}):
```

One of the ways I thought of was using a User-Defined Literal, like `100.0F` except instead of the preexisting literals, use decimal based operators like `100.0A` for absolute and `100.0R` for relative that's only associated with the `Coordinate` class. Is this possible?

My goal example:

```
public void SomeMethod(Coordinate 50.0R, Coordinate 25.0A, Coordinate 50.0R) 
{ 
    //... 
}
```

Or, if this is just not possible, is there other non-clunky ways to pass around decimal based numbers with the additional indicator as to if they are absolute or relative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `ValueTuple` would provide a really clean syntax to express what you're trying to achieve.

Tuples would provide a more intuitive syntax.

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Coordinate
        {
            public Coordinate((double Value, bool IsRelative) x, (double Value, bool IsRelative) y, (double Value, bool IsRelative) z)
            {
                X = x;
                Y = y;
                Z = z;
            }
            public (double Value, bool IsRelative) X { get; }
            public (double Value, bool IsRelative) Y { get; }
            public (double Value, bool IsRelative) Z { get; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"({X},{Y},{Z})";
            }
        }

        public static void SomeMethod(Coordinate coordinate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(coordinate);
            Console.WriteLine(coordinate.X.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(coordinate.Y.IsRelative);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var c = new Coordinate((100.0, true), (25.5, false), (100, true));
            SomeMethod(c);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

You do need the `ValueTuple` nuget package & C# 7

Comment: This looks like a very promising possibility. I'll try it out.

Comment: You can also use this constructor `public Coordinate(params (double Value, bool IsRelative)[] args)` to create a multi-dimensional coordinate system

Comment: Just tried this implementation. Works great and feels very "light-weight" to write. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't define your own custom suffixes in C#. I would assume that the most common use case would be having either all coordinates relative, or all coordinates absolute, so why not define two static methods on the `Coordinate` class for those cases:

```
var location = Coordinate.Relative(100.0, 25.0, 100.0);
var target = Coordinate.Absolute(100.0, 25.0, 100.0);
```

You could also make the constructor take a fixed number of dimensions, rather than an array:

```
var location = new Coordinate(100.0, true, 25.0, false, 100.0, true);
```

Comment: Your first answer would not work for my case as any of the values could be a mix of relative or absolute. Your second answer could work, but I'll leave this question open to see if I can get any other concepts.